# understanding magento directories

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento and don't have a magento2 directory because I installed it into public_html.

I ran `bin indexer:reindex` but got message `-bash: bin:` command not found

Please tell me how to fix this error:
"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

This confuses me
[Magento Officially Doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: command should be php bin/magento indexer:reindex.

Answer (score 3):

I think Your command Wrong:

Try

```
 <Magento Root Dir> bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

OR

```
 <Magento Root Dir> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```